# Автоматизация заполнения форм на сайте имея только url?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть задача. Надо автоматизировать процесс заполнения форм на любом сайте, имея только ссылку к сайту где в DOM имеется форма. Инструменты для данной задачи js, ajax, php. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

PS- для потенциальной площадки предназначенной для автоматизации размещению реклам на сторонних ресурсах, предоставляющие такую возможность.

Comment: тэга [tag:spam] не хватает что-то

Comment: А вам точно нужно именно заполнять формы? может лучше будет походить по этим ссылкам и пособирать адреса, куда эти формы уходят (а так же названия полей, заголовки и метод) и бомбить сразу туда соответствующие запросы?

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо за ответ,  просто первый раз столкнулся с такой задачей и сразу не додумался.